# Failed To Read File into Structure Array in C

Tags: c, structure

I tried to read the binary file into an array of structure. There will be a total of the records in the file at the beginning of the file and followed by all the records.

My plan is to read the file into a structure according to the total of records, use `malloc` enlarge the structure size, add more records into it, and overwrite the total of records and structure into the file.

```
void addRecord() {
    Staff* staff_data;
    int total;
    staff_data = read_data("staff_info.bin", &total);

    if (staff_data == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error reading from file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    staff_data = malloc(sizeof(Staff) * total + 1);

    printf("\n>>>>> Enter New Employee Details <<<<<\n\n");
    printf("Employee ID                : %d\n", staff_data[total-1].id +1);
    printf("Name                       : ");
    rewind(stdin);
    gets(staff_data[total].name);
    printf("Position                   :");
    rewind(stdin);
    gets(staff_data[total].position);
    printf("Phone Number               :");
    rewind(stdin);
    gets(staff_data[total].phoneNo);
    printf("Password                   :");
    rewind(stdin);
    gets(staff_data[total].password);
    printf("Date of Birth (DD-MM-YYYY) : ");
    scanf("%d-%d-%d", &staff_data[total].dob.day, &staff_data[total].dob.month, &staff_data[total].dob.year);
    printf("Date Joined (DD-MM-YYYY)   : ");
    scanf("%d-%d-%d", &staff_data[total].dateJoined.day, &staff_data[total].dateJoined.month, &staff_data[total].dateJoined.year);
    printf("Salary                : ");
    scanf("%lf", &staff_data[total].salary);
    printf("%s", staff_data[total].name);
    total++;

    if (write_data("staff_info.bin", staff_data, total))
        printf("Data Written Succesfully.\n");
    else
        printf("Error writing the file.\n");
}


Staff* read_data(char* filename, int* total)
{
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if (file == NULL) return NULL;

    if (fread(total, sizeof(int), 1, file) != 1) return NULL;

    Staff* data = malloc(sizeof(Staff) * *total);

    if (fread(data, sizeof(Staff), *total, file) != *total)
    {
        free(data);
        return NULL;
    }

    if (fclose(file) == EOF)
    {
        free(data);
        return NULL;
    }

    return data;
}

bool write_data(char* filename, Staff* data, int total) {
    FILE* file;

    file = fopen(filename, "wb");

    if (file == NULL) return false;

    // If fwrite got an error, return false
    if (fwrite(&total, sizeof(int), 1, file) != 1)
        return false;

    // If fwrite doesnt equal total, return false
    if (fwrite(data, sizeof(Staff), total, file) != total)
        return false;

    // If fclose doesnt work, return false
    if (fclose(file) == EOF) return false;

    // Everything works well, return true
    return true;
}
```

Im new to programming, I followed a video on youtube. The 2 functions are from the video but I dont really understand the code because I just learned the concept of pointer.

After reading the file, I found that when I tried to print the id of staff from the structure array, some random number will show up.
Output:

```
>>>>> Enter New Employee Details <<<<<

Employee ID                : -842150450
```

The same thing happens when I tried to print the name and other data, there are some unknown symbols instead of a readable string.

```
═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════²²²²▌▌▌p╒¶╓╫m
```

Comment: `staff_data = read_data("staff_info.bin", &total);` then `staff_data = malloc(..)` is not what you want. At best you're creating a memory leak by overwriting the pointer returned from `read_data`. If you want to expand your memory chunk, use [`realloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) instead

Comment: [Never use `gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2505965).